Why is my Transformer model outputting the same class for every token and not improving despite decreasing loss?
I'm currently training a Transformer model for a sequence classification task using CrossEntropyLoss. My input tensor has the shape (batch_size, classes, seq_len) and my target tensor has the shape (batch_size, seq_len).
However, I'm facing a strange issue:
Although the loss decreases with each epoch, the model's output does not seem to improve.
Specifically, the logits for each token in the sequence tend to zero, except for the first class which always goes to 1. Essentially, the model is predicting only the zeroth token for all positions in the sequence.
Here's an example of the class probabilities:
tensor([[1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]], device='cuda:0')

Does this behavior indicate that my model is not training correctly, or is there a potential bug in my implementation? Any insights or suggestions to diagnose and fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!

It seems that your issue could be either with the implementation of your training or with the data that you're providing.
If you've implemented the model yourself then it helps to sometimes look at the gradient values for your relevant parameter tensors.
You should also try to verify the tokenization and the activation functions of your model.

But thats definitly due to an error, or is it possible that it is simply not learnable?

Yep, seems like an error.
